# Correct use of ParseInstallation in Parse Push Notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been using parse for about 2 months for android and am very happy with it. I have built most of the app, just need to get push notifications finalized. I read the parse push guide and am able to receive and customize them.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseFeedBack.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseReportIssue.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseOrder.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseAddress.class);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }}
```

So the questions is

1. Do I leave `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation()` in the application class itself? Or shift it out to the main activity and register over there since I also want to identify the user associated with it, hence `ParseInstallation.put("userPointer", ParseUser.getCurrentUser)` will need to be added on my main activity.
2. Does this function have to be called everytime the user opens the app or only the first time? In which case I will place the code in the registration page so its called only once.
3. What happens If user A uses user B's phone to login. In that case this code `ParseInstallation.put("userPointer", ParseUser.getCurrentUser)` will associate installation on B with user A as he had logged in last. So If i send a targeted push notification to user A, it will be received on his as well as User B phone.
4. In `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`, I am overriding `onPushRecieve`, and building my notification over there. Im not placing any pending intent with the notification but instead overriding `onPushOpen()`. Is this recommended or should I just add a pending intent in the builder itself and leave `onPushOpen()` empty.
5. [Google metioned](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=en) that on October 15th. I noticed in manifest parse still uses C2DM. Have they released any blog about the changes they will implement?

.

```
public class MyPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    final Integer PRIORITY_MAX=2;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    String message;
    public MyPushReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
        builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            message=jsonObject.getString("alert");
            builder.setContentText(message);
            builder.setContentTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
            builder.setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX);
            int mNotificationId = 001;
            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                    (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());
            Log.d("PUSH ", jsonObject.toString()); 
            Log.d("s", intent.toString()); 
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Opening push!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of questions. I think you should read through the doc [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications) would be help or ask your questions separately.

Comment: I need answers to question 2 and 5 if you know them please?

Comment: For Q2, take look at [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/android-push-notification) page may help. For Q5, I think it ok for that, because the new GCM also contains `C2DM` in the `manifest file`, take look at [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest).